Read SD Card plugged into external device
My organisation is currently using an array of "song meter mini"  audio sensors that record bird song. They have no bluetooth/wifi/usb connection.
https://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/products/song-meter-mini-2-li-ion
The issue is that we have to go out and collect the sd cards and upload the data manually so an AI owned and operated by a 3rd party can analysis the audio. This is taking a huge ammount of time and uploading the data is effecting the office interenet speeds (rural internet) for other users. We are getting further and further behind on uploading the data and it may make the project unviable.
We are looking for a solution to this and one idea is to use a Rapsberry pi with 4g hat to read the data and upload it as it is created, this issue is that this would entail reading data off the sd card that is plugged into the audio sensor, or more likely into a SD card extender. From what I've read it may be possible to do this by hardwiring into the SPI bus but havent found any guides or details on this.
Is it possible? Or is there any kind of splitter that could take the data both to the pi and an external sd card? Or any guides that look at this problem?
Wifi-SD Cards have been suggested and I will look into that.
Thanks!

research wifi SD card

Paul - As I understand your question, it has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi per se, but more along the lines of "How can I (we) download the contents of SD cards deployed in the field (and plugged into audio sensors)?" If that interpretation of your question is correct, you should be searching for a solution that provides the ability to connect via Bluetooth or WiFi (whichever your sensors have available), and read the SD card's contents. If that interpretation is not correct, please edit your question.

Also, you shouldn't overlook the power requirements of your "Rapsberry pi with 4g hat" idea. Raspberry Pi's are generally of limited use in off-grid applications (i.e. running from batteries) due to their relatively high energy consumption.

Why not do your AI processing using an AI hat on a Pi? Ask on the Pi forums https://forums.raspberrypi.com/

You have not presented any information about the "audio sensor"! If the Raspberry Pi was the audio sensor it would be a clear YES but without info its is a big "perhaps".

Thanks everyone for the comments. I have updated the details of sensors we are using. I didn't know SD wifi cards existed though, that could be the way forwards.
